# Companion matrix for $(x^2+1)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, companion-matrices

I know how to find campanion matrix from polynomial.but in Kurtis linear algebra book I found [image]

In that$ (a_{14}) $entries is 1 .from my calculation s I got everything  correct except that . Where I am main mistake.

Sorry for writing without much as writting form mobile..
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The companion matrix is similar to the one exhibited in the figure. Yes, there should be a $1$ in the $(1,4)$-th entry, otherwise the minimal polynomial would become $x^2+1$, which is different from the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Ohhhh thanks.but can you explain how to get 1 there.i do not understand lemma presented in book? Thanking you

Comment: I don't know. I haven't access to that book and the author's definition of companion matrix seems to be quite different from the [standard one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), but the matrix as shown in the figure is definitely similar to a matrix whose minimal polynomial is $(x^2+1)^2$.